# Cordova 6.0 IOS Load External URL in the WebView

Tags: ios, cordova

I am new to Cordova and could use some help doing a simple task.

I have this hello world application where I am trying to load an external url on the application WebView, the code I am using is the one generated by cordova, the only changes I did to it were:

- Added a link to `http://www.google.pt` on the index.html file.
- Added `<allow-navigation href="*" />` to the config.xml file.

I have carefully read the documentation and as far as I can tell, this very simple change should allow me to load the url in the app, however, it does not. Once I click the link, safari opens and google loads. I need it to load inside the app, not in safari.

I have tested the exact same thing on android and it works perfectly.

Here is my config.xml file:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
</widget>
```

Here is my index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 20px; border: 1px solid grey;">
             <a href="http://www.google.pt/">Google!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using cordova 6 and testing on ios simulator with ios 9.2, also tested with 8.1 and also doesn't work.

Any idea whats wrong?

Thanks,
Cipri

Comment: I'm having this problem too. The solution below didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10942) in Cordova to work around just delete the `<allow-intent>` that have http and https in `href`

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

Like this

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />

    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>

    <allow-navigation href="*" />
</widget>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Removing the two allow-intent didn't fix it.

Comment: @TomKincaid You need to edit code in index.html and config.xml files under staging folder platforms/ios path properly.